# How to add a popup in Django admin to link back to the current inline record

Tags: django-admin

I have a group of models something like:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)

class GrandChild(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Child)
```

Within Django admin I can set the `Child` as an `admin.TabularInline` for `Parent`.  I want to add a link which will pop a window allowing me to Add a GrandChild

At the moment I can create a list of existing `GrandChild` records by including the following within my `admin.TabularInline` for the `ChildInline`

```
def grand_children(self, obj):
    text = ''
    for grandchild in obj.grandchild_set.filter(completed=False):
        text += grandchild.name + '<br />'
    return mark_safe(text)
grand_children.short_description = 'Grand Children'
```

I would like to add something that pops a Django admin popup (like it does on a ForeignKey relationship) to add a `GrandChild` linked to the associated `Child`.

I don't know how to pop the window with the `Child` id set.  Can you help?

Comment: Try to add http://admin_url?_popup=1 to the URL

Comment: Did you try to change the formset of your admin.TabularInline? I think you can override `BaseInlineFormSet` using `inlineformset_factory` or `ModelForm` using `modelform_factory`  to specify your own widgets

Comment: @SylvainBiehler I haven't done any of that.  Sounds like it might work and I'll take a look